# Trying to store file names in current directory with zip extension in a string array in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a class that extracts the contents of a zip file that is in the current working directory.  However it only works if I know the filename.  What is the best way to grab the names of files that just end in .zip into a String array so I can have my program unzip the files listed only in the array?  Much thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Arrays.stream(new File("./").listFiles()).filter(f -> f.getName().endsWith(".zip")).forEach(f -> {
        do something
    });
```

In ***Java8***, you can use ***filter***